# How to add the classes which are designed by me into java library ? (to use "import" keyword in other classes )

Tags: java

I want to use the classes (that are .java files) which I designed separately in java and I want to add them into java library to use them in other classes with "import" keyword. How can I do this ?

Also, I should explain that I copied the classes folder in the zip file which its name is `src.zip` at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25` but when I use the "import" keyword in the IDE it seems that there is not any folder with that name in java library.

Comment: Read about `JAR` files and `CLASSPATH` variable.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do with src.zip, or what that has to do with your classes...

Comment: To be clear -- if you specifically want to add you classes to a 'java.*' package -- you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand this correctly but you need to make a `jar` file from your library project and then place that `jar` file into the project which wants to use that library. How do you do this depends mainly on the `IDE` which you are using.

[Add library in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893349/java-how-to-add-library-files-in-netbeans)

[Add library in  Eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

[Add library in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

Comment: no... i want to add my classes to java library... like " import java.util.* "  i want to import my classes in every other classes. for example i want to import my classes like this expression : " import java.myClasses.* ; "

Comment: so how can i make a jar file ?

Comment: For example like this (in the library root folder) `jar cvf library.jar *`, then add this jar to your other projects

Comment: Add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25/bin/jar` to the PATH, then execute above command from command line.

Comment: Do the same like in this tutorial http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml, except you need to add `jar` not `java` for this task

Comment: Or simple use your IDE to create it for you, try to google the tutorial for it

Answer (score 0):

What needs to be available to Java are the object (aka `.class` files).  So, you can do 2 things:

1. Locate the directory where you `.class` files are and add it to the CLASSPATH (either by changing the environment variable, or by specifying switch `-cp` to java).  Be careful with one thing:  if you have a class MyClass in package stackoverflow.com, in the directory structure you will see something like .../com/stackoverflow/MyClass.class.  The base folder to include in CLASSPATH is .../com, not .../com/stackoverflow .
2. Packaging your classes into a `.jar` file (pretty much a `.zip`, but with a different extension), and add it to the CLASSPATH as in 1.  Note that n this case you use the name of the `.jar`, not the name of the directory it is in.

`src.zip` does not contain classes, but source (`.java`) files.  That's why its extension is not `.jar`, and also why you don't see any effect.