# Trying to import opencv into java project

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans

I'm using netbeans to do a face tracking project. I'm trying to import opencv libraries but it says it's not found. I'm not sure how to add the library into netbeans. 
Under project properties in the libraries I added the opencv lib - at the org folder /OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/java/android_test/src/org

```
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
```

I'm using MacOSX 10.8.5 and I installed opencv using homebrew.

Any help please. Thank you.

Comment: it will help I hope http://stackoverflow.com/q/5893349/1021970

Comment: I did that, I'm just not sure if I'm pointing to the right folder for the libraries