# Json library for java on netbeans

Tags: java, json, netbeans

I have an issue , i need to use json for java and i try to import a it's library by this way :

**import org.json.simple.JSONObject;**

but it don't work , it says that the package org.json.simple does not exist .

any help please

**(I use netbeans)**

Comment: What build tool are you using? MAven or ant?

Comment: hem , no one , in fact i don't know what are you talking about , i  have searched and i ound that it has something to do with maven but i couldn't understund , please explain to me .

Comment: `org.json.` doesn't belong to standard Java packages. You need to download it and add to project classpath.

Comment: If you or not using maven or ant, your project still has a library/class folder. You need to put the json jar into your class/lib folder

Comment: i have tried to import the jar file as a library but it's not working too ??

Comment: can you explain me how to do a clean import and what i have to add as syntax , thank you

Comment: Here you can find informations about how to add library/jar to your project in NetBeans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893349/java-how-to-add-library-files-in-netbeans

Answer (score 2):

Using a class that is not in part of the standard JAva library requires a bit more than just importing it by way of an import statement. The most direct way to accomplish this is to download a jar file to the local environment and add the jar to your build path. Alternatively, you can use a tool like Maven to manage your dependencies, but this is a bit more involved.

SimpleJSON can be downloaded from [here}(https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/list). Adding it to your build path depends on the IDE you are using, but instructions should be readily available on the interwebs.

Noticed you stated you used [Netbeans](http://oopbook.com/java-classpath-2/classpath-in-netbeans/)

Comment: thank you, i've done what you said but it steel not working , when i creat an object from a class of the imported jar , it's says that the class don't exist