# Netbeans build error in Java project

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, compiler-errors

I am not able to Clean and Build my NetBeans java project. Output says:

> error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while
>   constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor:
>   Provider
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor
>   could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/persistence/internal/sessions/AbstractSession

Here:

> .../nbproject/build-impl.xml:930: The following error occurred while
>   executing this line:
>   .../nbproject/build-impl.xml:270: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Lines from build-impl.xml:
Line 270 -

```
<javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
```

Line 930 -

```
<j2seproject3:javac gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>
```

I am trying to find some help on forums, but i am so hopeless. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Make sure that the eclipse.persistence.core*.jar is in your classpath.

Comment: I have NB under Ubuntu 16.04 (just info). How to check this classpath please? (any link to guide)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, How to add library files in netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893349/java-how-to-add-library-files-in-netbeans)

Comment: I've found some answer about including EclipseLink (JPA 2.0) library to my project. It seems that this error disappear. Will see if this solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a constructor in your class. I've faced the same problem and that simple action solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer would be better if you included some example code to illustrate the solution.

Comment: Your answer has the potential to be a good answer. You are familiar with the problem and you have solved it. Just [edit] your question and add some sample code demonstrating how you _create a constructor in your class_.