# Error: NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I get next error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:955)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:87) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 3 more

I use intellij idea and imported 2 libs: httpclient-4.5.5.jar and httpcore-4.4.9.jar

All libs in my class:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
```

And code sample:

```
    String urlToSendRequest = Constants.HOST + Constants.URL;
    String targetDomain = Constants.DOMAIN;

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(targetDomain, 80, "http");

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlToSendRequest);

    httpPost.addHeader("SENDCODE", "UTF-8");
    //...

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(Constants.MSG, "UTF-8");
    entity.setContentType("application/xml");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I'm almost sure that the problem is with libraries importing, but I'm not sure and have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Try adding `commons-logging` to your classpath.

Comment: Looks like u are missing Apache Commons libs , please improt those. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776415/apache-httpclient-throws-a-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551697/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-logging-logfactory

Comment: I'd love an answer that doesn't say "Then add it..."  I CAN'T add it due to company policies here - what can I do?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please download the commons-logging jar file and set the path.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi

Comment: Thank you. it's really strangely, because I have already try this, but now it's works. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Please include commons logging jar in your project.
Can be downloaded from [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi)

Also from  [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are missing commons-logging lib.